# How to change the words color in a text using regex - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on JavaScript Regex, and I want to change the colors of the words,

`Socket:`, `Database:`, `Scrapper:` only.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript Regex ?

This is my Text:

```
Socket : Sockets Connection Made on ID : dBGWu_Y4nSI40QEPAAAB
Database : Connected to MYSQL Database Successfully...
Scrapper : Scrapper Initiated, Please wait while we load the URL...
Scrapper : The Page ""+MAIN_URL+"" loaded Successfully !
Scrapper : The Page SNAPSHOP has been taken !
Scrapper : Total jobs Found on this site : 1093 and Total Pages : 110
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !
Scrapper : --------------------------------ALL PAGES ARE SCRAPPED SUCCESSFULLY---------------------------
```

It's basically the `ul > li` elements, in which I want to change the colors of some words.

I tried this :

`$(".log-container").text().match(/(scrapper :)/gi)[0].css({color:"orange"});`

But didn't work for me

Comment: Text doesnt have css properties.  You would have to wrap the text in question in html elements and style those.

Comment: What do you mean wrapping text in question ?

Comment: `<span class="red">Scraper:</span> rest of line text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

Replace

```
(Socket|Database|Scrapper)(\s*:)
```

with

```
<span style="color:blue">$1</span>$2
```

will wrap the words in a span setting color to blue.

```js
text = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(Socket|Database|Scrapper)(\s*:)/gi, '<span style="color:blue">$1</span>$2');
  
console.log( text );
document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
Socket : Sockets Connection Made on ID : dBGWu_Y4nSI40QEPAAAB<br/>
Database : Connected to MYSQL Database Successfully...<br/>
Scrapper : Scrapper Initiated, Please wait while we load the URL...<br/>
Scrapper : The Page ""+MAIN_URL+"" loaded Successfully !<br/>
Scrapper : The Page SNAPSHOP has been taken !<br/>
Scrapper : Total jobs Found on this site : 1093 and Total Pages : 110<br/>
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !<br/>
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !<br/>
Scrapper : The Page Current Jobs are evaluating ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page Click, Please wait ...<br/>
Scrapper : Next Page is Loaded, and SNAPSHOT has been taken !<br/>
Scrapper : --------------------------------ALL PAGES ARE SCRAPPED SUCCESSFULLY---------------------------<br/>
```